# Google Drive API problems in handling properties

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Hi I have succesfully integrated google drive api, but I have some problems when trying to use the paremeters given in the response. What I want is to read the paremeters of the object "parents".

In my case i want to read "id" and "isRoot". But if I use

```
echo ($result[7]->parents->id);
```

or

```
echo ($result[7]->parents->isRoot);
```

I get nothing as an answer (I have checked and this is an element contained in one folder). Can anyone tell me how to read those fields?

Kind regards, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`$result->parents` will be an array - a file can have multiple parents on Google Drive. So in order to read `id` and `isRoot`, you have to pick one of the parents (e.g. the first) or go through all of them, depending on what you are trying to do.

```
$result[7]->parents[0]->id
// or
foreach ($result[7]->parents as $parent) {
   ...
}
```